# Function for creating a simple node with optional attributes

Tags: javascript, dom

I’m trying to create a simple function that accepts one compulsory ‘node’ variable, and two other optional ‘class’ and ‘id’ variables. The function runs correctly when you specify all 3 elements - but it doesn’t allow you to, for example, create an element without an id but with a class or vice versa.

My code is below:

```js
var testEl = createEl('div', 'testClass', 'testId');

function createEl(node, theClass, id) {
  var newNode = document.createElement(node);
  newNode.classList.add(theClass);
  newNode.id = id;
  return newNode;
}

document.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].innerHTML = testEl.outerHTML; // fails why?
console.log(testEl.outerHTML);
```

```html
<p>This should change</p>
```

Is there a way that this function could be improved so you could create variables like this for example:

```
var el = createEl(node = ‘span’, id = ‘someId’);
```

Any tips would be very helpful. Thanks for any help here.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/ns91/pen/KKwaQRY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named parameters don't exist in JavaScript. That means if you want to make some parameters optional, the caller will have to provide a value for each parameter up to the optional one. E.g. to call your function without a class but with ID:

```
createEl('div', '', 'testId');
```

---

I suggest to use an *object* to hold all the attributes instead. An advantage is that you can just iterate over that object and assign the values to the DOM elements:

```js
function createEl(node, attributes) {
  var newNode = document.createElement(node);
  for (var prop in attributes) {
    newNode[prop] = attributes[prop];
  }
  return newNode;
}

createEl('div', {id: 'foo'});
createEl('div', {className: 'bar'});
createEl('div', {id: 'foor', className: 'bar'});
```

You can also add special treatment to some properties, such as `classList` (up to you how you want to handle it):

```js
function createEl(node, attributes) {
  var newNode = document.createElement(node);
  for (var prop in attributes) {
    switch (prop) {
      case 'classList':
        attributes[prop].forEach(cls => newNode.classList.add(cls));
        break;
      default:
        newNode[prop] = attributes[prop];
    }
  }
  return newNode;
}


createEl('div', {classList: ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just assign the parameters a default value or something so when the user calls your function with missing parameter that default value is used. Read about it here, https://www.markhansen.co.nz/javascript-optional-parameters/

```
function createEl(node, theClass = someClass, id = someId) {

  var newNode = document.createElement(node);
  newNode.classList.add(theClass);
  newNode.id = id;
  return newNode;
}
```

so with the code above you can call `createEl(node)`

Edit: You need to have some kind of check in your function for those values being default or empty or undefined in case you want to do something else in that case.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function createEl(node, optional) {
  if(typeof optional === "object"){
    var { theClass, id } = optional;
  }
  var newNode = document.createElement(node);
  theClass && newNode.classList.add(theClass);
  id && (function(){ newNode.id = id})();
  return newNode;
}
// Usage -1
var testNode = createEl('span', {theClass: 'myClass', id: 'myID'});

// Usage -2
var testNode = createEl('span', {id: 'myID'});

// Usage -3
var testNode = createEl('span');
```